# DbSet query with AsExpandable() and async throws InvalidOperationException (IDbAsyncEnumerable)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.6

I'm trying to run an async query based on an `Expression<Func<>>`:

```
Expression<Func<IDbUserRightsInfo, bool>> expression = u => u.MarketingType == eUserMarketingType.Internal;

var result = await (from u in usersDbSet.AsExpandable()
             where expression.Invoke(u)
             select u).ToArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But it does not work. The exception I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.

If I remove the await/async it works fine but I want to use it.

It seems to be caused by the `AsExpandable()` method, but it is required in order to use the built `Expression`.

Comment: What is `usersDbSet`?

Comment: It is a System.Data.Entity.DbSet<User>

Comment: you prolly have wrong LinqKit version ... if you take a look [here](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/src/LinqKit.Core/ExpandableQuery.cs#L30) `ExpandableQuery` implements `IDbAsyncEnumerable` but only in one case ... so there must be multiple versions of LinqKit each for given EF version

Comment: eventually it is a problem of translation from query syntax to C# ...  so you could try using C# syntax

Comment: What database you are using ?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL.

Comment: I'll try to use the LinkKit.Core ExpandableQuery you linked.

Comment: Thanks @Selvin. Indeed with LinqKit NuGet it works. I was previously using a version from a few years ago that was imported in our own project and didn't support IDbAsyncEnumerable.